# Error aligning equation while using latexocr and mathtype

Tags: align

I'm using latexocr to snip equation and translate it into latex, then insert it in office word using mathtype, im trying to align this equation on two lines such the 3rd and 4th "=" align with each other. This my latex code

```
$\begin{align*}{c}{{S(P,h,\alpha)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}h(t_{k})\;\Delta\alpha_{k}&=c_{1}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(t_{k})\;\Delta\alpha_{k}+\;c_{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}g(t_{k})\;\Delta\alpha_{k}}}\\ {{&=\,c_{1}S(P,f,\alpha)\,+\,c_{2}S(P,g,\alpha).}}\end{align*}$
```

but latexocr didn't display the code and instead just show "Misplaced &" on the screen. I tried it with overleaf and it works fine (with some red warning). I'm not a latex user so i don't understand much about this, can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: a "red warning" is not a warning it is an error which means any output is not useable, `{{&=` can not work, you can not start two groups then end a cell with `&` without closing the groups.

Comment: if latexocr is for scanning equations and generating latex, how are you using that with latex that you are writing as latex code??

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
\begin{align*}
  S(P,h,\alpha) &= \sum_{k=1}^{n}h(t_{k})\;\Delta\alpha_{k} \\
                &= c_{1}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(t_{k})\;\Delta\alpha_{k} + c_{2}\sum_{k=1}^{n}g(t_{k})\;\Delta\alpha_{k} \\
                &= c_{1}S(P,f,\alpha) + c_{2}S(P,g,\alpha).
\end{align*}
```

Comment: It worked in latexocr but not when i copied it to mathtype.

Comment: @alksdhalksjdb - mathtype may use syntax that looks like LaTeX, but its underlying rendering engine is non-LaTeX. That's why mathtype-related issues are off-topic for this site.